# Cannot create desktop shortcuts to Windows URI

Tags: windows, shortcuts, url, uri, protocol-handler

I am trying to create a desktop shortcut to a windows URI, e.g. `ms-settings:privacy`. Sites such as https://winaero.com/windows-11-uri-commands-to-launch-apps-directly/#Create_shortcut_for_URI_command indicate this should be possible by pasting the URI into the "target" box of the normal Create Shortcut wizard.

However, when I do this, it creates a *URL* shortcut instead. Although the properties dialog shows the target correctly, clicking the shortcut will launch the default web browser, as if it is expecting a weblink. This evidently happens any time I create a shortcut targeting a URI containing a `:` (colon symbol). Conversely, I can open a URI through the `Win + R` Run dialog just fine.

I've looked through the default assigned protocols in Windows Settings > Apps, and I don't see anything amiss. I'm guessing there may be some registry entry that controls URI/URL shortcut management, but I have no idea what it might be or how it might have been altered.

Can anyone shed some light on my situation?

Comment: While there are many similarities between Windows 10 and Windows 11, you have not actually indicated, you are running Windows 11 but linked to an article that likely only applies to Windows 11.

Comment: Windows 10 - the shortcut runs correctly in Settings by my test.

Comment: @Ramhound apologies for not indicating. This feature is not unique to windows 11, as others have pointed out, but regardless I *am* running W11

Comment: @ETL - I am aware it’s not unique to Windows 11, but there are significant differences at times between the two versions of Windows, so your question explicitly indicating your Windows 11 is helpful

Answer (score 0):

It's not as graceful as a built-in windows shortcut feature such as the non-working one suggested in your link, but you can get this done with a batch file instead.

- Open notepad
- Paste this: `start ms-settings:privacy`
- Save it as whateveryouwant.txt
- Replace .txt extension to .bat
- double click the .bat file and it should work as intended

You can always change the icon of the file if you want to make look more representative of what it does.

Comment: I know, this is my current workaround :/ Was hoping to fix the root problem though